# How do I use AirDrop from the Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, airdrop

Is there a way to share a file over AirDrop via Terminal on Mountain Lion? How so?

Comment: In what way? To send or receive files? It's finder functionality so to be honest I doubt it, but there maybe some AppleScript hyjinx depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: duplicate question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26021/airdrop-how-to-access-airdrop-from-command-line/367073

Answer (score 8):

I have not (yet) figured out a way to **send** files via Airdrop using the Terminal, but you can set your computer to **receive** files via Airdrop using the following shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "R" using {command down, shift down}
end tell
```

Comment: This would be really handy if you didn't need to accept each transfer. Perhaps that could be scripted as well.

Answer (score 7):

There is now a reverse engineered open-source version of AirDrop known as [OpenDrop](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/opendrop) that runs on MacOS and Linux - it allows for sending and receiving of files on the command line with other AirDrop/OpenDrop capable devices (e.g. [OpenDrop can run on a Raspberry Pi](https://owlink.org/2019/05/16/howto-use-airdrop-on-raspberry-pi-3.html)). To send you need to first discover the available devices e.g.

```
opendrop find
```

The chosen receiver is selected (by `index`, `ID` or `name`) and a file is sent:

```
opendrop -r id -f /path/to/some/file
```

File reception is more straightforward - files will be downloaded into the current directory:

```
opendrop receive
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool on Github called **[terminal-share](https://github.com/mattt/terminal-share)** that claims to offer this functionality:

```
terminal-share -service airdrop -image path/to/image.jpg
```

But it's not clear to me how you specify a destination..

Comment: I gave up on that tool long ago but gave it another try and found this solution to the bug. https://github.com/mattt/terminal-share/issues/11#issuecomment-800791854 I use Mission Control to get the always-on-**bottom** (bug) share window onto its own desktop where I can interact with it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do so using [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/). It's not completely automatic since you still have to select your phone.

opendrop doesn't work on the iPhone unfortunately.

[I've written a blog post about this](https://www.lucanaef.com/automating-airdrop/)

Add the following to your `init.lua`

```lua
local hex_to_char = function(x)
  return string.char(tonumber(x, 16))
end

local unescape = function(url)
  return url:gsub("%%(%x%x)", hex_to_char)
end


hs.urlevent.bind("airdrop", function(eventName, params)
    local file = unescape(params["f"])
    print(file)
    local url = hs.sharing.fileURL(file)
    local ad = hs.sharing.builtinSharingServices.sendViaAirDrop
    local s = hs.sharing.newShare(ad)
    s:shareItems({url})
end)
```

This will construct an endpoint to the hammerspoon Custom URL that can receive filenames as input.

Then you can create a script like this

```bsh
#! /usr/bin/bash

rawurlencode() {
  local string="${1}"
  local strlen=${#string}
  local encoded=""
  local pos c o

  for (( pos=0 ; pos<strlen ; pos++ )); do
     c=${string:$pos:1}
     case "$c" in
        [-_.~a-zA-Z0-9] ) o="${c}" ;;
        * )               printf -v o '%%%02x' "'$c"
     esac
     encoded+="${o}"
  done
  REPLY="${encoded}" 
}

rawurlencode "$@"

/usr/bin/open -g "hammerspoon://airdrop?f=${REPLY}"
```

This will URL-encode the input and send it to the `airdrop` custom URL which we've registered with hammerspoon.

Save this somewhere as `airdrop` file in your `$PATH`, `chmod +x` it (make executable), and then you can `airdrop <myfile>`

Answer (score 3):

No - the functionality is programmed into the core OS and lacks official hooks supplied by Apple via the command line.

Comment: I wish they would add that. Until then, `scp` will continue to be my friend.

Answer (score 3):

I created a CLI tool a few years ago that does what you want:
https://github.com/vldmrkl/airdrop-cli

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can also automatically set your AirDrop receiving setting to "Everyone", script based on [None of the above's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/64720/270632):

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "Finder"
    make new Finder window
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    keystroke "R" using {command down, shift down}
    # open the "Allow me to be discovered by" dropdown
    click button 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
    # select the 3rd option (Everyone)
    click radio button 3 of pop over 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
end tell
```

Comment: Ah yes, that does it! But how does one know IDs/names of the GUI controls, such as `splitter group 1` (*and their nesting level*)? Is there some debugger/inspector for Mac OS windows controls?

Comment: ...found it - standard `Accessibility Inspector` tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "R" using {command down, shift down}
end tell'
```